# Error trying to delete record Entity Framework (Validating for delete?)

Tags: entity-framework, validation, entity

I'm trying to delete a record, but when it comes to the line where " SaveChanges()" says EF displays an error saying that certain related fields are required.

Any ideas? This is giving me a headache

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, EF validates only Added and Modified entities. So, maybe you overrided method `ShouldValidateEntity` and always return `true`?
You can change it this way:

```
protected override bool ShouldValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry)
{
    if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but I have overloaded that method , however , I added debug and step by step, I see the status of the entity that attempts to erase appears as if to edit ... ?

The strange thing about all this is that checking more thoroughly, I see that only 5 entities related to my main entity listed as valid to remove as it seems , the related foreign key and just as are those that are marked " required "